# SAS auto log clear with rsubmit

Tags: sas, remote-server, wrds

I used to add `dm "out;clear;log;clear;";` to clear the log and prevent the code from pausing for input. However, now I am using WRDS remote connection. This line after rsubmit does not work and the I lost connection to the server because I was not by the computer when the log was full and needed for user input to be cleared. Is there a way to prevent the code from stopping? Here is what I am doing now.

```
options ls = 78 ps = 66;

********************connect to WRDs;***************************************;
%let wrds = wrds.utexas.edu 4016;options comamid = TCP remote=WRDS;
signon username=_prompt_;
*************************************************************************;

rsubmit;
libname qa"F:\research2\transcripts";
libname cq '/wrds/nyse/sasdata/taqms/cq';


proc upload data=qa.daylist out=daylist; run;
data daylist;set daylist;traday2 = input(put(traday,yymmddn8.),8.);drop traday;rename traday2=traday;run;
options errors=2;

data intraday;run;
%macro temp;
%do i = 1 %to 2215; 
.......
dm "out;clear;log;clear;";
%end;
%mend;
%Temp;
```

Comment: Why are you generating the log if you are just going to delete it without reading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (which avoids the need to clear the log) is to write the log to an external destination using `proc printto` (doc [link](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n1oardywxmmut7n1pol0zkj5u1ok.htm)).  The syntax is:

```
proc printto log='/path/to/your.log';
run;
```

Comment: Right, I tried the above approach yesterday. But it still breaks with the error msg: ERROR: Conversation termination; status=1.
ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you
       can communicate with WRDS.
ERROR: Remote submit to WRDS canceled. I think the approach worked, and this time it should be due to a CPUTIME issue?

Comment: @AngelChen - yes, you are missing the `signon` statement.

Comment: ? I had it in the third line of the code as: signon username=_prompt_;

Comment: aah - seen.  Then it seems there was an issue with signon. I suggest creating a new question for this issue!  As it is unrelated to the question asked here..